# Return a list of sublists contained in the original list with sums

Tags: scala

I have a list of parts, and combos which are a list of parts.

I have a parts list for a car, and I want to see how many combos belong in the parts list and also get the sum of the weight.

So I want to return a list of combos that are contained in hondaParts, along with the total weight.

```
  case class Part(id: Int, weight: Int)
case class Combo(parts: List[Part])

val part1 = Part(1, 1)
val part2 = Part(2, 1)
val part3 = Part(3, 2)
val part4 = Part(4, 5)
val part5 = Part(5, 3)
val part6 = Part(6, 8)
val part7 = Part(7, 2)
val part8 = Part(8, 12)
val part9 = Part(8, 1)

val allParts = List(part1, part2, part3, part4, part5, part6, part7, part8, part9)

val combo1 = List(part1, part2)
val combo2 = List(part4, part2)
val combo3 = List(part7, part8, part9)
val combo4 = List(part3)

val combos = List(combo1, combo2, combo3, combo4)

val hondaParts = List(part1, part3, part4, part7, part8, part9)
```

So basically I want a list of all combos that are inside of the hondaParts list.  And then I want to get the sum of the weight for each combo.

I tried this:

combos.forall(hondaParts.contains)

But then just returns bool.

Comment: I believe what you need is `combos.filter(_.forall(hondaParts.contains))`

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there—you just want need an extra `filter` so that you're checking `hondaParts` for each element of each combo (rather than for the combo itself):

```
scala> combos.filter(_.forall(hondaParts.contains))
res0: List[List[Part]] = List(List(Part(7,2), Part(8,12), Part(8,1)), List(Part(3,2)))
```

This reads as "select each combo such that for each of its elements, `hondaParts` contains that element".

As a side note, the fact that `combos.forall(hondaParts.contains)` is an unfortunate artifact of the way equality is handled in Scala. It doesn't really make sense to ask whether a list of parts contains a list of parts, but the compiler will happily let you do that with `contains` without even a warning. You can make things a little safer by putting the intended type parameter on `contains`:

```
scala> combos.forall(hondaParts.contains[Part])
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Part => Boolean
 required: List[Part] => Boolean
       combos.forall(hondaParts.contains[Part])
                                        ^
```

But the corrected version will compile just fine:

```
scala> combos.filter(_.forall(hondaParts.contains[Part]))
res1: List[List[Part]] = List(List(Part(7,2), Part(8,12), Part(8,1)), List(Part(3,2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are correct. But what you get is a `List[List[Part]]`. In order to get the sum, you can `flatten` and `fold`. Example:

```
val parts = combos.filter(combo => combo.forall(p => hondaParts.contains(p))).flatten
val sum = parts.foldLeft(0)((sum, part) => sum + part.weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use the Combo case class to instantiate the combo1, combo2, combo3, combo4. Then the solution is straightforward:

```
case class Part(id: Int, weight: Int)
case class Combo(parts: List[Part])

val part1 = Part(1, 1)
val part2 = Part(2, 1)
val part3 = Part(3, 2)
val part4 = Part(4, 5)
val part5 = Part(5, 3)
val part6 = Part(6, 8)
val part7 = Part(7, 2)
val part8 = Part(8, 12)
val part9 = Part(8, 1)

val allParts = List(part1, part2, part3, part4, part5, part6, part7, part8, part9)

val combo1 = Combo(List(part1, part2))
val combo2 = Combo(List(part4, part2))
val combo3 = Combo(List(part7, part8, part9))
val combo4 = Combo(List(part3))

val combos = List(combo1, combo2, combo3, combo4)

val hondaParts = List(part1, part3, part4, part7, part8, part9)

val filteredCombos = combos.filter(x => x.parts.intersect(hondaParts).size == x.parts.size) 

val comboWeights = filteredCombos.map(x => x.parts.foldLeft(0)((a,b) => a + b.weight))
```